# Class generated from complex xsd, trying to serialize gives nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Been scratching my head for some hours. Googled as well. But can't figure out how to generate the xml properly. Would highly appreciate input that could help me figure this out. I've used xsd.exe earlier together with less complex schemes without any problems.

So I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have created C# Classes from this xsd-file: http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd

I created the classes with the Microsoft xsd.exe tool like this: xsd.exe xsd-file /classes

Then I removed double brackets like [][] and replaced with single [], otherwise I cant serialize/deserialize at all.

I actually don't know the correct way to create a xml-file with the class generated from the xsd-document. Here is an example of such a xml-file: https://github.com/mlt/schwinn810/wiki/Sample-.TCX-Files

This is my object that I'm trying to serialize (just an example):

```
XmlObjects.Tcx20.TrainingCenterDatabase_t tcx = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.TrainingCenterDatabase_t();
XmlObjects.Tcx20.AbstractSource_t abstractSource = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Application_t();

abstractSource.Name = "TcxCreator";

tcx.Author = abstractSource;
abstractSource = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Application_t();

XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityList_t activityList = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityList_t();

XmlObjects.Tcx20.Activity_t[] activity = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Activity_t[1];
XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityLap_t[] lap = new ActivityLap_t[1];
XmlObjects.Tcx20.Course_t[] course = new Course_t[1];
XmlObjects.Tcx20.Trackpoint_t[] trackPoint = new Trackpoint_t[1];
XmlObjects.Tcx20.Position_t position = new Position_t();

double lat = 10;
double lon = 11;

position.LatitudeDegrees = lat;
position.LongitudeDegrees = lon;

trackPoint[0].Time = DateTime.Now;
trackPoint[0].Position = position;
lap[0].Track = trackPoint;
activity[0].Lap = lap;

activityList.Activity = activity;

tcx.Activities = activityList;
```

Line trackPoint[0].Time = DateTime.Now; gives the mentioned error. But i think its more related to that im creating the classes/xml wrong compared to how the xsd/xml looks like.

Could someone just point me in the right direction concerning how to build up the xml from the class generated by xsd.exe?

Edit: Thanks YavgenyP! That was it, this code is working:

```
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.TrainingCenterDatabase_t tcx = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.TrainingCenterDatabase_t();
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.AbstractSource_t abstractSource = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Application_t();

        abstractSource.Name = "TcxCreator";

        tcx.Author = abstractSource;
        abstractSource = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Application_t();

        XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityList_t activityList = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityList_t();

        XmlObjects.Tcx20.Activity_t[] activity = new XmlObjects.Tcx20.Activity_t[1];
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.ActivityLap_t[] lap = new ActivityLap_t[1];
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.Course_t[] course = new Course_t[1];
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.Trackpoint_t[] trackPoint = new Trackpoint_t[1];
        XmlObjects.Tcx20.Position_t position = new Position_t();

        double lat = 10;
        double lon = 11;

        position.LatitudeDegrees = lat;
        position.LongitudeDegrees = lon;

        trackPoint[0] = new Trackpoint_t {Time = DateTime.Now, Position = position};
        lap[0] = new ActivityLap_t {Track = trackPoint};
        activity[0] = new Activity_t {Lap = lap};

        activityList.Activity = activity;

        tcx.Activities = activityList;
```

Comment: So I get one downvote... how should I rephrase? I've been scratching my head for several hours and couldn't think of a solution. Been googling a lot as well. Should I add some more information? What? I could add the whole class generated by xsd, and the xsd itself, but it's an awful lot of text... please guide me.

Comment: Exactly which line produces the NullReferenceException? Just dumping the code on us and saying there's a problem _somewhere_ is likely to be what caused someone else to downvote.

Comment: Line trackPoint[0].Time = DateTime.Now; gives the mentioned error. But i think its more related to that im creating the classes/xml wrong compared to how the xsd/xml looks like. Should I post my xml object generated by xsd.exe? Maybe someone could tell easily how to build the document up?

Comment: You probably got a downvote because its a debugging issue, which, it seems at least, you avoided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Line trackPoint[0].Time = DateTime.Now; gives the mentioned error

Look at your code, you initialize the aforementioned array here:

```
XmlObjects.Tcx20.Trackpoint_t[] trackPoint = new Trackpoint_t[1];
```

but you never initialize the Trackpoint_t ITSELF in the array, which causes this

```
trackPoint[0].Time = DateTime.Now;
```

to fail (trackPoint[0] is still a null)